# Failed routing when deploy React + Express.js app on IIS server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, url-rewriting

I have a React app created by Create-React-app and Redux together with Node.js (specifically Express.js) backend. In the frontend package.json file I set "proxy: http://localhost:5000" to redirect all the api calls from react app to backend server. In the meantime, the backend server is concurrently run and listen on the localhost: 5000 port.

The app structure is shown below:
[App Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BKkc.png)

## **Frontend**

The package.json file in the client folder (frontend) setup the proxy like this

```js
{
  ...,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

In App.js (Frontend entry point) I have created a bunch url routings with react-router-dom:

```js
 return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Fragment>
          <Router>
            <div
              className='App'
              style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: '500' }}>
              <header>
                <Navbar />{' '}
              </header>

              <div>
                <Routes>
                  <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
                  <Route exact path='/home' element={<Home />} />
                  <Route exact path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
                  <Route exact path='/about' element={<About />} />
                  <Route exact path='/register' element={<Register />} />
                  <Route exact path='/login' element={<Login />} />
                  <Route exact path='/forgot' element={<ForgotPassword />} />
                  <Route path='/reset' element={<ResetPassword />} />
                  <Route path='/avatar' element={<ChangeAvatar />} />
                  <Route
                    exact
                    path='/systemtables'
                    element={<SystemTables />}
                  />
                  <Route exact path='/profiles' element={<ProfileMain />} />
                  <Route exact path='/companies' element={<CompanyMain />} />

                  ...
                  
                </Routes>
              </div>

            </div>
          </Router>
        </Fragment>
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
);
```

## **Backend**

The package.json file in the app root (AAQCS folder) looks like this:

```js
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js --ignore temp/",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "clientinstall": "npm install -prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

In "web-server.js" (backend entry point) I have below code:

```js
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());
    httpServer = http.createServer(app);
    //Set server side static uploads folder receiving front-end upload request.
    app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

    // Combines logging info from request and response
    app.use(morgan('combined'));

    //Init Middleware to receive request body
    app.use(express.json({ extended: false, limit: '50000mb' }));
    app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/images/favicon.ico'));

    //Serve any static files built by React
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
    });

    //Define Routes
    app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
    app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
    app.use('/api/asset', require('./routes/asset'));
    app.use('/api/companies', require('./routes/companies'));
    ...

    httpServer
      .listen(webServerConfig.port)
      .on('listening', () => {
        console.log(
         `Web server listening on localhost:${webServerConfig.port}`
        );

        resolve();
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
      });
```

Backend server listening on localhost:5000.

Currently I have these rules in web.config file:

```js
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="RedirectToBackend" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^api/(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:5000/api/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^api/(.*)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
```

Everything works when I am in development environment, all the routings are working.

After I put the build in IIS, I can launch the Login page but when I hit Login button, I got error: **"POST `http://localhost:3000/api/auth` 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)"**

My questions are:

1. Is there anything wrong in my routing rules in the web.config file?
2. Basically what I want to achieve is all the api calls with the format "/api/xxxx" should be redirected to localhost:5000 where backend server is listening. All other request without the "/api/xxxx" format should follow the routings set up in the react app. How can I create rules to achieve this.

Comment: `<action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:5000/api/{R:1}" />` is invalid. You cannot just redirect the browsers there (that URL is invalid on browser side machines), and need to set up a full reverse proxy.

Comment: So I changed type to Rewrite and installed ARR just as @Yurong Dai suggested.  Now I got logged in successfully but not all react routings working although I set up the routings exact the same in App.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install ARR and enable the proxy feature to work with IIS as a reverse proxy, which can forward all api calls in the format "/api/xxxx" to the backend NodeJS server.

[image: image1]

Make sure the URL rewrite action type is set to "Rewrite" and not "Redirect" since you want to proxy the request rather than perform a redirect.

```
<rule name="RedirectToBackend" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^api/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/api/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Additionally, all other requests without the "/api/xxxx" format should follow the route set in the React application. You need to create the following rule that will rewrite all non-API requests to the root URL ("/") where the React app's routing will handle them.

```
<rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api/(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. I've logged in correctly. I also got most of the non-API call handled correctly with your rules above with the except of some routings when I clicked on the button, for example: the server gave me **Cannot GET /assessmentaudits** message. I had the exact same routing setup in App.js as others like /login, /register, etc,. Is this something that I have to specifically write this url in the  rules?

Comment: Something more with above error though: when I hover on the button trigger the `assessmentaudits` component, it shows the link of `http://localhost:3000/assessmentaudits` at the bottom left corner of the screen. But when I hit the button, the url in the browser actually turned into `http://localhost:5000/assessmentaudits` which caused the above error. What did I do wrong? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you set the route '/assessmentaudits' corresponding to the assessmentaudits component in App.js? Have you created any other rules besides the rewrite rules in the above answer?

Comment: I suggest you try using FRT to trace the request, you can see how the rules are used internally. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes I had this code in App.js: `<Route exact path='/assessmentaudits' element={<AssessmentAudits />} />`. I remembered when I checked Enable proxy in ARR, I also checked Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests under Proxy Type section and put `localhost:5000` in the Reverse proxy box. After I see your answer I unchecked the Use URL Rewrite to inspect incoming requests and apply the change. Would that leave a "other rule" in the system? I will definitely go through your FRT tracing suggestion tomorrow and let you know the result.

Comment: Solved the problem when I changed **"/assessmentaudits"** url to **"/asmtaudits"** in React routings in App.js. Don't know why it happened. Maybe that url coincidentally matched the first level of our domain which is **"assessmentaudit.ma....."** ( how could this happen even the domain name doesn't have "s" ended). Thank you so much for your help YurongDai. You are the man!!!